# Dense versus sequentially dense in $\mathcal{E}’$

Tags: schwartz-distributions

Endow the dual space $\mathcal{E}’$ of smooth functions $C^\infty$ (with its metrizable topology described by uniform convergence on compacts for convergent sequences) with the weak* topology. Let $D$ be a dense subset of $\mathcal{E}’$. Is it true that $D$ is also sequentially dense in $\mathcal{E}’$?